# HTML <a> element does not fill the whole cell with 100% height

Tags: html, css

I have a table in which in a 'td' tag I have a link ('a' element). What I would like to achieve is to make the whole 'td' tag clickable for the hyperlink. My solution so far:

```
<td class="wholeBlockLink">
    <a href="#">Torok, Zoltan</a>
</td>
```

The CSS code:

```
.wholeBlockLink a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.wholeBlockLink:hover {
    background-color: #ffff66;
}
```

I attach an image which shows that the element does not fill the full height of the cell:
[image: a href in a td tag]

As you can see, the td tag's size is 96px x 37px, but the a's element size is 96px x 17px. So for some reason the width attribute works but the height not.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: height:100% require a css rule in parent with explicite height value , else you get 100% of nothing .

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you set the height of your table and row to 100%, it should fix your anchor (as long as the table's container doesn't have an explicit height set):

```
table, tr { height: 100%; }
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/pv5ha/1)

if you want to keep your vertical alignment to middle, then you will need to add an extra span:

```
<a href="#"><span>Torok, Zoltan</span></a>
```

and use display table and table cell:

```
.wholeBlockLink a {
    display:table; 
    width:100%;
    height:100%; 
}

.wholeBlockLink a span {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/pv5ha/2)

Comment: Thanks, it's working! Can I please ask you, what's the difference between the display:table/table-cell and block? Because as I see, you've changed my block to table/table-cell.

Comment: table and table-cell just make the the div behave as if you were using an actual table with tds instead (which gives you better use of vertical alignment).  If you look at the block one in the first example, the text is aligned to the top of the anchor where as in the table-cell version it is in the middle

Answer (score 1):

you need to make some changes in css

use this

```
.wholeBlockLink{margin:0px; padding:0px;}
.wholeBlockLink a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none; background:#F00;
    display:block;
    padding:20px 0px;
    margin:0px;
}

.wholeBlockLink a:hover {
    background-color: #ffff66;
}
```

Comment: Seems like everyone is suggesting to put padding. We're dealing with dynamic cells, so i'm thinking he doesn't want to hard code pixels.

Comment: Yes, you're right I need dynamic cells so padding and fix pixels are not good for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use line-height to be the same as your td height. `line-height:37px;`

Comment: Unfortunately my td's height depends on dynamic content, so it's not a solution. And also the line-height is already set beforehand (163%)

Comment: Unfortunately this will only work if you define height and width for the td, cause 100% width and height dont help if the parents has not a defined height and width.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly set the height of the parent element, otherwise the % calculation has no reference point.

Give the `td` a height of say, `37px;`

Answer (score -1):

Now this may look super hacky, but simply change your "a" from "display: block" to "display: table".  I imagine you don't want to mess with padding, line-height or any type of "static" hard-coded value.  Try this and it'll work.

```
.wholeBlockLink a {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: cyan;
}
```

It works here http://jsfiddle.net/WLaAg/

Comment: Ummm can someone explain the -1 please?  Did you see the fiddle?

Comment: i did not downvote, i guess it is because it doesn't work in Chrome ? a comment should be sufficient enough

Comment: Ahh, seems like it worked on FF and not on Chrome. I get the padding, but what if the height of the cell gets increased further.  You're banking on the fact that the height of the cell is static.  Anyways... probably better to use javascript click event to bind that cell.